# Pass a JavaScript array to a function in Scala.js

Tags: scala.js

Using `import js.Dynamic.{ global => g}` I am able to access the MathJax library as `g.MathJax`, but I can not find how to pass a function argument when calling a function from MathJax. I currently have the following: `g.MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", g.MathJax.Hub])` which results in `illegal start of simple expression` which is of course because I am using square brackets, but I don't know how to properly pass the array with scalajs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JavaScript array is typed as a `js.Array` in Scala.js. So the square brackets "constructor" for arrays can be written with `js.Array(...)`, like this:

```
import scala.scalajs.js

g.MathJax.Hub.Queue(js.Array("Typeset", g.MathJax.Hub))
```

More information on what Scala.js correspond to what JavaScript can be found [in the documentation](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/types.html).